# Find the breaking time in IVP for classical Burgers equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

> Consider Burgers equation $u_t+uu_x=0$, such that $$ 
> u(x,0)=\phi(x)=\left \{\begin {array}{lll}
> 2, & x\leq \pi/2\\
> \sin x+1, & \pi/2\leq x \leq 3\pi/2\\
> 0, & x \geq 3\pi/2\\
> \end{array}
> \right..
> $$
>
> Find the breaking time $t_B.$

**Attempt.** We easily get the characteristic curves $x=\phi(r)t+r$ ($r$ parameter). So:

for $r<\pi/2$ we get $x=2t+r,$

for $\pi/2<r<3\pi/2$ we get $x=(\sin r+1)t+r$ and

for 
$r>3\pi/2$ we get $x=r.$

The "limit" curves $x=2t+\pi/2$ and 
$x=3\pi/2$ meet at time $\pi/2$, and also the curve $x=(\sin \pi+1)t+\pi=t+\pi$ meets the above at time $\pi/2$. On the other hand though, the curve $$\displaystyle x=\Big(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)t+\frac{5\pi}{4}$$meets $x=t+\pi$ and some time $<\pi/2$. So, how can I find the minimum of the times these curves intersect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does $\sin x+1$ means $\sin(x+1)$ or $\sin(x)+1$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a partial answer, hoping it will help :

FIRST PART : Solving $\quad u_t+uu_x=0\quad $without taking account of the initial conditions.

Set of characteristic differential equations : $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{0}$

A first equation of characteristic curve comes from $du=0\quad\to\quad u=c_1$

A second equation of characteristic curve comes from $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{c_1} \quad\to\quad x-c_1t=c_2$

General solution on the form of an implicit equation :
$$\Phi\left(c_1\:,\:c_2\right)=\Phi\left(u\:,\:x-ut\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables. An equivalent form is :
$$u=F\left(x-ut\right)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function of one variable.

SECOND PART :

Particular solution with regard to the initial condition $\quad u(x,0)=\phi(x)$
$$u(x,0)=F(x+0u)=F(x)=\phi(x)$$
$$u(x,t)=\phi(x-ut)$$
The function $\phi$ is defined as :
$\quad \begin{cases}
\phi(\theta)=2\qquad\text{if } \quad \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\\
\phi(\theta)=\sin(\theta)+1 \qquad\text{if }\quad \frac{\pi}{2}\leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}\\
\phi(\theta)=0\qquad\text{if } \quad \frac{3\pi}{2}\leq\theta
\end{cases}$

We introduce a dummy variable $\theta$ in order to not confuse $x$ when $t=0$  with $(x-ut)$ when $t\neq 0$.

Thus the solution is :
$$\quad \begin{cases}
u=2\qquad\text{if } \quad (x-ut) \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\\
u=\sin(x-ut)+1 \qquad\text{if }\quad \frac{\pi}{2}\leq (x-ut) \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}\\
u=0\qquad\text{if } \quad \frac{3\pi}{2}\leq(x-ut)
\end{cases}$$

$$\quad \begin{cases}
u=2\qquad\text{if } \quad x \leq 2t+\frac{\pi}{2}\\
u=\sin(x-ut)+1 \qquad\text{if }\quad ut+\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x \leq ut+\frac{3\pi}{2}\\
u=0\qquad\text{if } \quad x \geq\frac{3\pi}{2}
\end{cases}$$

From this, it is possible to draw the curves $x(t)$ for various specified values of $u$.

Note that : $\quad 0\leq u\leq 2$

The figure below shows $u$ as a function of $x$ for various values of $t$ (Drawn from numerical calculus) :

[image]

$u=0$ for $t>\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and/or $x>\frac{2\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 4):

The initial data $u(x,0) = \phi(x)$ is continuously differentiable, with derivative
$$
\phi'(x) = 
\left\lbrace
\begin{align}
&0 && \text{if}\quad x\leq \pi/2 \, ,\\
&\cos x && \text{if}\quad \pi/2\leq x \leq 3\pi/2 \, ,\\
&0 && \text{if}\quad 3\pi/2 \leq x \, .
\end{align}
\right.
$$
In the case of Burgers' equation $u_t + u u_x = 0$, the time $t_B$ at which a shock occurs (or the minimal time where characteristic curves intersect) is given by [(1)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3WhqLPcMdPsC&lpg=PP1&hl=fr&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)
$$
t_B = \frac{-1}{\min \phi'(x)} = 1 \, .
$$
This is illustrated in @JJacquelin answer, and in the following sketch of the $x$-$t$ plane:

[image: characteristics]

---

*Note* : cf. exercise 3.3. of

[(1)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3WhqLPcMdPsC&lpg=PP1&hl=fr&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) R.J. LeVeque, *Numerical Methods
for Conservation Laws*. Birkhäuser, 1992.

Comment: Hi. I have a doubt in that formula of LeVeque. When I take the minimum of $u'_0(x)$, I get the maximum of the time, not the minimum (first time breaking)... I am studying this book and stucked here. Could you explain? Many thanks.

Comment: @Na'omi Hello! Details can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2445518)

Comment: Thank you, I will study this.