# ODE IVP : $u_t + uu_x = 0, \; \; u(x,0) = \cos \pi x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

**Exercise :**

> Show that a **smooth** solution of the initial value problem
>   $$\begin{cases} u_t + uu_x = 0 \\ u(x,0) = \cos \pi x \end{cases}$$
>   must satisfy $u = \cos[\pi(x-ut)]$. Also, show that when $t=1/u$, the function $u$ stops to exist (as a single-value function).

**Attempt :**

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{u} = \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{0} $$

$$\implies u_1 = u, \; \; u_2 = x - ut$$

Which means that the solutions are given by $u_1 = F(u_2) \Rightarrow u = F(x-ut)$. Thus, taking into account the initial value : $F(x) = \cos \pi x.$ Now, for $x:= x-ut$ we get $F(x-ut) = \cos[\pi(x-ut)]$ which $\in C^\infty$ and thus a smooth solution.

**Question :** How would one proceed to show the second part of the exercise ? It gives as a hint to check the graphs of $\arccos(u)$ and $\pi(x-ut)$ as functions of $u$, which makes sense, since :

$$\arccos(u)=\pi(x-ut)$$

But I can't seem how to grasp out a graph or figure out a solution to it.

Comment: Hint: it's called Burger equation

Comment: @rafa11111 Could you elaborate more ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to this kind problem. I will think a little. What I mean is that this equation is a classical problem of a discontinuous solution arising from an apparently 'well-behaved' problem. The inexistence of the solution for Burgers' equation for given conditions is a classic result of nonlinear PDE's.

Comment: Cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2763316/418542) and related ones

Comment: Do you mean $t = 1/\pi$ for solution $u$ to be multivalued?

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799257/why-is-the-solution-single-valued for the second part of your question.

Comment: Another thing, @Rebellos. Are you sure that the statement is right? Isn't it for $t=-1/u_x$?

Comment: @rafa11111 Yes. I am sure.

Comment: @Rebellos check pg. 5 here: http://www.bcamath.org/projects/NUMERIWAVES/Burgers_Equation_M_Landajuela.pdf and pg. 5 here https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/physik_tp/lectures/ws2016-2017/num_methods_i/burgers.pdf, viz.